# Python .format adding extra quotes to string when using psycopg2

Tags: python, string, postgresql, psycopg2

Hope someone can help as i'm getting myself tied in knots here.

Trying to copy a table and output it as a CSV using python, psycopg2 and postgresql.  I need to have the table name and output file name as variables because I will be later changing tablename to an array so it can loop through multiple tables.

My code is below, but I keep getting the following error, seems an extra set of quote marks are being added.  Anyone know how to get round this please?

fullTempBaseURL is: C:\Administrator Files\Worksorders.csv

fullRawCSVURL is: G:\Team Drives\RawCSV\Worksorders.csv

syntax error at or near ""C:\Administrator Files\Worksorders.csv""
LINE 1: copy (SELECT * FROM "Worksorders" ) to "C:\Administrator Fil...

```
import psycopg2
from config import config
from psycopg2 import sql
import os

tablename = 'Worksorders'
tempBaseURL = 'C:\Administrator Files'
RawCSVBaseURL = 'G:\Team Drives\RawCSV'
fileType = '.csv'

global fullTempBaseURL
global fullRawCSVURL

fullTempBaseURL = tempBaseURL + '\\' + tablename + fileType
fullRawCSVURL = RawCSVBaseURL + '\\' + tablename + fileType

print "fullTempBaseURL is: " + fullTempBaseURL 
print "fullRawCSVURL is: " + fullRawCSVURL

###########################
#Copy table to CSV
###########################

def tabletoCSV():   

    conn = None

    try:
        # read database configuration
        params = config()
        # connect to the PostgreSQL database
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        # create a new cursor
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # execute the SQL statement
        cur.execute("SET search_path TO dbo")
        cur.execute(sql.SQL("""copy (SELECT * FROM {tbl} ) to {url} with csv""").format(tbl = sql.Identifier(tablename), url = sql.Identifier(fullTempBaseURL)))
    # commit the changes to the database
    conn.commit()
    # close communication with the database
    cur.close()
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()

def moveFile():
    os.rename(fullTempBaseURL, fullRawCSVURL)

tabletoCSV()
```

Thanks in advance,  Jon

Comment: There is a lot of code that seems irrelevant to the problem. Making a [mcve] might help in getting an answer.

Comment: Noted for next time, but can you help?

Comment: It's hard to see what causes the problem here. My best guess is that you might have quoted the file path in table style instead of making it a string constant. Although that's pretty much what the error message already told you, so I'm not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file name should not be an identifier, it should be quoted in single quotes. You can use a `sql.Literal` instead.

Comment: Can't upvote because I don't have the reputation but thanks so much Piro!!